# Rounding value in the where LINQ MVC ASP.NET

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a query made ​​in the archive of wonder how could truncate a value column in order to make the comparison:

follows the script query:

```
var query = from ies in db.TB_LV
            where ies.rod_id == nmRod &&
                (ies.km_i) >= vlrkmI &&
                ies.km_f <= vlrkmF &&
                ies.dt_levant == ultLev
            select ies.ies;
```

and the values ​​of `km_i` `km_f` column to decimal values ​​while `vlrKmI` and `vlrKmF` are integer values.

I need to truncate the values ​​of `km_i` and `km_f` column to the query. 
Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Try: `(int) ies.km_i >= vlrkmI`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To truncate the values ​​of  **km_i** and **km_f** , you need to change your query like this.

```
  var query = from ies in db.TB_LV
                where ies.rod_id == nmRod &&
                    (int) ies.km_i >= vlrkmI &&
                    (int) ies.km_f <= vlrkmF &&
                    ies.dt_levant == ultLev
                select ies.ies;
```